# Extracting alphanumeric, integers, floating numbers from string using Python3.6

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
s= "Classic for older systems.  People •  Animals •  Food • ⚽ Activities •  Travel •  Objects •  Symbols ...45.6"
```

I want to remove symbols, emojis, •

Expected output is as follows:

```
"Classic for older systems  People   Animals   Food   Activities   Travel   Objects   Symbols 45.6"
```

Code:

```
re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', s)
```

produces

```
'Classic for older systems  People   Animals   Food   Activities   Travel   Objects   Symbols 456'
```

It is removing dot from floating point number. How can I fix this?

Comment: What about `(?:[^\w\s.]|_|(?<!\d)\.)+` or `(?:[^a-z\d.\s]|(?<!\d)\.)+` using case-insensitive flag? You can also use `(\d\.\d)|[^a-z\d\s]` using case-insensitive flag and replace with `$1`

Comment: How do you know it's floating point instead of a dot ? I don't believe you can tell the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/HHdq0m/2)

```
(\d+\.\d+)|[^a-z\d\s]+
```

- `(\d+\.\d+)` Captures decimal numbers into the first capture group: One or more digits, dot, one or more digits
- `[^a-z\d\s]+` Matches one or more of any characters that are not alphanumeric or whitespace. Using the `i` (case-insensitive flag) this also matches uppercase variants.

Replacement: `$1`

Outputs:

```
Classic for older systems  People   Animals   Food   Activities   Travel   Objects   Symbols 45.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mimic `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` with:

```
import re

s = "Classic for older systems.  People •  Animals •  Food • ⚽ Activities •  Travel •  Objects •  Symbols ...45.6"

rx = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+|(\W+)')

def replacer(match):
    if match.group(1) is not None:
        return ' ' * len(match.group(1))
    else:
        return match.group(0)

s = rx.sub(replacer, s)
print(s)
```

This uses a function `replacer` as replacement and yields

```
Classic for older systems     People      Animals      Food      Activities      Travel      Objects      Symbols    45.6
```